# How do I replace numeric interval in string with a mean of interval endpoints in R?

Tags: r, string, replace

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("bought, 2.500-2.700,- bar, 1000",
                       "545,-kc, barista 3600-4600kc sells",
                       "about  3-4 thousands",
                       "sold 2.000-3.000,-, table"))

df
      A
[,1]  bought, 2.500-2.700,- bar, 1000
[,2]  545,-kc, barista 3600-4600kc sells
[,3]  about 3-4 thousands
[,3]  sold 2.000-3.000,-, table
```

I want to replace the intervals with a mean of the endpoints. The desired output looks like this:

```
      A
[,1]  bought, 2.600,- bar, 1000
[,2]  545,-kc, barista 4100kc sells
[,3]  about 3,5 thousands
[,3]  sold 2.500,-, table
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Unless I am not seeing it, this is actually a fairly involved NLP problem.

Comment: I think that there is a number of typos in the numbers. I will edit. Apologies if these were not typos and I misunderstood something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

repl <- df$A %>%
  str_extract_all("\\d*\\.?\\d+-\\d*\\.?\\d+") %>%
  str_split("-") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  unlist()

df$A %<>% str_replace("\\d*\\.?\\d+-\\d*\\.?\\d+", repl)

df
```

Output:

```
                              A
1       bought, 2.6,- bar, 1000
2 545,-kc, barista 4100kc sells
3          about  3.5 thousands
4             sold 2.5,-, table
```

Comment: I have so many observations that it runs forever. I suppose that it is caused by the fact that mutate.all function has to change 300k+ columns (the data frame has two rows) and it would be easier to work with a transposed data frame (two columns and 300k+ rows). How would you do it?